# Reading from gridview with two headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using ASP.NET with C#. I have `GridView` and needed to have two headers. So I used the following code to add another header after data binding.

```cs
gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
gridView.DataBind();
GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell
{
    Text = titleST,
    ColumnSpan = 5
};
row.Controls.Add(cell);
row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3AC0F2");
row.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
row.BorderColor = Color.Black;
row.BorderWidth = Unit.Parse("2");
gridView.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
```

The issue is that when I try to read the data from the `gridView`, somehow the first row does not have data.
This is how I read the data:

```cs
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
{
    int atmpt = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlAttemptsT")).SelectedIndex;
    Int64 selId = Int64.Parse(((HiddenField)row.FindControl("SelId")).Value);
    double wt = int.Parse(row.Cells[2].Text);
    double grade = double.Parse(((TextBox)row.FindControl("grade")).Text);
}
```

I am thinking that I added the new header at index 0 which remove the first row. But In GUI the first row exists. I tried to do `AddAt(-1, row)` but that will add it at the bottom of the `gridView`.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?
Please, let me know if I need to clarify my question more.
Thank you

Comment: Might want to show at least a small code snip of how you are reading the grid?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I added that. Thank you

Comment: That should work just fine. There must be more markup, maybe a up-date panel, some detail here is missing. With what you posted so far, I don't see an issue. As noted, update panels or some other detail here is missing. I would post the markup of the grid - and if any update panels etc, then include that - and the button markup you have when clicked that runs your above code stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a problem of persistence.

When the GV is bound - it also sets up some "things" for view state and how it remembers the layout.

if you AFTER binding, add the header? Then it will display, but is NOT persisted (since it was changed after binding + setup).
So, with the existing layout - you do in fact wind up over writing the first row.

This means you need to add DURING the binding process.

So, use the RowCreated event. And put your code in that event - say like this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridViewRow Myrow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header,
                DataControlRowState.Normal);
            TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell
            {
                Text = "My cool title",
                ColumnSpan = 5
            };
            Myrow.Controls.Add(cell);
            Myrow.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3AC0F2");
            Myrow.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            Myrow.BorderColor = Color.Black;
            Myrow.BorderWidth = Unit.Parse("2");

            // heading actauly does not exist yet
            GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.Add(Myrow);
        }
    }
```

And you ONLY bind the grid on post back = false now. Any way, try the above, it should persist, and your first row should now be ok.

Comment: Thank you @AlbertD.Kallal. This solved the issue. @